# Not able to use d3.max

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, d3.js

I want to adjust the scale on the x axis and I wish to find the max using d3.max function but cannot seem to get a result on the x axis. The code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adeun9wp/)

The code I am using is the following,

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0,d3.max(d3.values(donnees), function(d) { 
                    return d.xValue;
                        }
                )])
            .range([0, w]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First mistake:**

You should be declaring the `donnees` object before finding its max.

**Second Mistake:**

```
d3.values(donnees)//this will give 2 array object
```

You will need to get the merged array of the datasets and then find the max with in it.

Do the merge of the two arrays like this: `var merged = [].concat.apply([], d3.values(donnees));`

Now find the max of the merged array like this:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,d3.max(merged, function(d) { 
                        return d.xValue;
            }
           )])
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/adeun9wp/2/)

Hope this helps!